# How to create Liferay hook in order to extend functionality of shopping cart portlet

Tags: java, liferay, portal

Can anyone help me out on how to create a hook within Liferay for the shopping cart portlet? I would like to implement custom code at the point of a successful order. Any help is appreciated.

I've tried reading the documentation for overriding services:
http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Portal+Hook+Plugins

but I'm not sure what the service would be that I need to override.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to find it yourself is to use Liferay IDE and let the "New Hook" Wizard guide you. You can rely on Liferay's naming conventions. The shopping cart services all start with "Shopping", e.g. ShoppingOrderLocalService.

In this class, take a look at the methods in that class. Extend the Liferay implementation as the default implementation (best practice) and only implement the methods, where you want to add changed behaviour. You can call super to retain the old implementation (you typically want this) or just ignore that call if you completely change the behaviour.

Comment: I have similar problem. I would like to remove the paying icons (VISA etc.) and create own method of paying. How to remove the pictures?

Comment: I could remove the functionality but not picture. @Olaf do you have any idea?

Comment: without looking it up (no time for that currently), the images are probably in the JSPs, so you can remove them by overriding the jsps. Maybe there's a configurable option, but I've never customized the shopping portlet, so I don't know first hand. Through a jsp hook you could probably also introduce new images for your new payment method.

Comment: @OlafKock...hi....i want to add my own method into existing calendar portlet..here is my question and code...can u please look at it and let me know were i am doing wrong.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747253/adding-custom-methods-in-hook-environment