# How to get all the users list in Kaleo Workflow on Assign to Combo box?

Tags: workflow, liferay, liferay-6

I am working in Liferay Portal. I have created my custom work flow and created the portlet to start the work flow. I am done successfully with this but I am facing one problem, when the user clicks on **Assign to** button from **Workflow Tasks** to assign the task to some other user the combo box which display available users, it only display the users who has the **Administrator or Owner Roles**.

As i have developed custom work flow in which i have defined my own roles, i wish to display the users with that roles in the combo box. I have searched a lot but not able to get the proper solution for this.

If anyone has any idea please kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you have to create a hook and you have to write the code in file named "workflow_task_action.jsp" within Workflow_task.....

In this file code for that combobox which you require is available.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But can you tell me how i can create hook? As I am new to Liferay...

Comment: Just refer this link it will help you out....http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/hooks